# Is there a program that will show me the average CPU usage over the last minute for every process?

Tags: monitoring, top, resources

One feature I miss from Windows is that the Resource Monitor program would show, among other statistics, the average CPU usage over the last minute for each program. On Linux I use either Gnome system monitor or `top` to monitor processes, but neither program offers this feature from what I can tell.

A common use case for these programs for me is "my laptop fan just flared up for no apparent reason. What program is eating up my CPU?" Often, however, by the time my fan turns on and I switch windows into `top` the process has stopped, so I can't see which process it was. This is where it is useful to have an average over the last minute.

So does anyone know how I can get `top` to show this or something similar, or another program that can do this?

Comment: Read `man htop top ps` You can set the measurement interval, probably to 20 seconds.

Comment: Maybe you could use `atop` or the script I wrote for alerting about processes using more than 75% of CPU: https://github.com/birdie-github/useful-scripts/blob/master/alert-bad-processes